# Custom Code and Parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to use the custom code option to pull down the querystring and set the parameters for the report all in the custom code. So I may have a url such as:

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.aspx?ProjectID=1
```

I would want the code in the SSRS custom code to pull down that `1` and put it in the parameters for the report. So when I run the report it shows the data with the ProjectID of 1.

Is this possible to do in Reporting services? If so, how would one go about doing this. Thanks for any help I have seriously been trying to figure this our for weeks.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the real scenario? is the URL passed to SSRS report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS can parse a parameter value from the URL as long as it's in the format *parameter=value*. See [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

The sample URL in your question doesn't look like a report server URL, so (like bhupendra indicates) it's hard to know exactly what you're doing.